# Why pod goes to CrashLoopBackOff after restarting successfully few times due to liveliness probe failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, livenessprobe, crashloopbackoff

I've a simple spring boot application with following liveness probe:

```
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 56017
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
```

In the health endpoint, I simply throw an exception causing it to return 500. Here is an statistics of a fresh pod after watching many restarts:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\yyy\Desktop> k get pods -n xyz  -w

NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            0          15s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            1          69s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            2          2m10s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            3          3m10s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            4          4m10s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            5          5m10s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          6m8s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            6          7m33s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m28s
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            7          11m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          12m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            8          17m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            9          18m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          19m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            10         24m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   1/1     Running            11         25m
springapi-577c6f94b9-9r4lm                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   11         26m
```

I notice that first couple of restarts are quick as expected. Then #3, #4, #5 are 1 minutes apart. So far kind of makes sense. After that I start seeing CrashLoopBackOff and time between two restarts goes up to 5 minutes apart. Why CrashLoopBackOff? and why restarts are so much apart after few restarts?

I saw the logs of the pod. Nothing unusual. The log output is something like this (these logs are after many restarts):

```
2021-04-04 00:46:49.172 DEBUG 1 --- Spring boot startup stuff ...
...
2021-04-04 00:47:23.121  INFO 1 --- Spring boot startup stuff ...
2021-04-04 00:47:23.178 ERROR 1 --- exception stack trace
2021-04-04 00:47:33.010 ERROR 1 --- exception stack trace
2021-04-04 00:47:43.005 ERROR 1 --- exception stack trace
2021-04-04 00:47:43.092  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

When I run describe command, I see messages like

```
Container springapi failed liveness probe, will be restarted
Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Back-off restarting failed container
```

Btw, during these 5 minutes, the pod remains in **CrashLoopBackOff** state. I've restarted the pod many times. I see same behavior everytime.

Answer (score 3):

I found this explanation in an article:

```
Failed containers that are restarted by the kubelet are restarted with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped at five minutes, and is reset after ten minutes of successful execution.
```

Looks like its an expected behavior.

Comment: 1+ that is indeed correct, you should also look into `startupProbe`...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue related to pods. The same **CrashLoopBackOff**  error and regarding  **livenessProbe** and **readinessProbe** with ***400*** error in the events.

The thing I missed is to create a API in the service application which we mentioned in the path. *(Here in this question is "path: /health".)*

I created a API with "/health" deployed it again and it starts working as expected.

Atul